# ncftpget on amazon ec2 not working (centos)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, centos

I have set up an Amazon EC2 instance running CentOS 6. I've installed ncftp and I intend to use CRON to automatically pull backups from a private NAS drive overnight for backup. I have also mounted a s3 bucket using s3fs which I'm using as the target directory.

When I connect manually using ncftp, I'm able to connect and list files over FTP. When I use ncftpget to recursively download all files, the command appears to do nothing - I see no files in the target directory even after letting it run for a considerable amount of time.

Can anyone tell me why the ncftpget command is unresponsive? Are there firewall issues I haven't considered? Is there a better way to approach my problem?

```
[root@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX /]# ncftp -P 21237 -u admin XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
NcFTP 3.2.5 (Feb 02, 2011) by Mike Gleason (http://www.NcFTP.com/contact/).
Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX FTP server ready
Logging in...
Password requested by XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX for user "admin".

Password required for admin

Password: *********

User admin logged in
Logged in to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
ncftp / > cd array1/
ncftp /array1 > cd StandoutDigital
ncftp /array1/StandoutDigital > ls
folder1/
ncftp /array1/StandoutDigital >
[2]+  Stopped                 ncftp -P 21237 -u admin XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
[root@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX /]# ncftpget -R -T -v -P 21237 -u admin XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX /s3bucket/ /array1/StandoutDigital
Password: *********
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 ncftpget -R -T -v -P 21237 -u admin XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX /s3bucket/ /array1/StandoutDigital
[root@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX /]#
```

Comment: Have you checked logs?

Comment: which ones? I can't find any logs for ncftpget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used lftp instead in the end.